# Download plugin jar file and put it in the lib/ext

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a problem that I want to execute JMeterPluginsCMD.bat command so I just download the jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar file and put it in the lib/ext folder but I still cannot run JMeterPluginsCMD.bat command. I' m wondering if the JMeterPluginsCMD.bat file should show in my bin folder after putting jar in the lib/ext? If it should, then why my JMeterPluginsCMD.bat file is not shown? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `JMeterPluginsCMD.bat` file you can grab one from here:

https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/tools/cmd/src/main/resources/kg/apc/cmdtools/JMeterPluginsCMD.bat

Be aware that the recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

1. [Install JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Installation-and-Usage)
2. Restart JMeter
3. Open the plugins manager and install **Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool**

   [image]
4. Restart JMeter once again and you will have `JMeterPluginsCMD.bat` in your JMeter's "bin" folder

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try using  plugins manager later. Cause I met some problem when install plugins(I remember that  some plugins I did not choose can not be removed show in the console and cause problem). So I cannot install JmeterPluginsCMD just like installing PluginsManagerCMD by put jar file in lib/ext then run some kind of procedures in GUI mode and create the .bat file?